# Android Long Polling TCP Connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, long-polling

im trying since month to do a proper "push" without using external librarys or gcm.

First i tried xmpp with asmack, then mosquitto with paho or ibm mqtt client and http with alarmtimer.

Finally i ended with deacon and meteord but since it's not very good (on server side - high cpu and memory load) im trying to do a longpolling connection.

I know that it requires a heartbeat and finally i was thinking about the Delay (300 seconds heartbeat should be enough?) and the proper way.

Is it better (battery usage and so on) to send a Heartbeat (with 1 Byte or whatever) from server to client (delay for example 300 seconds) and setting a socket timeout on client side of 300, or is it better to do send it from the client to the server?

Currently im using a Service which register an observer in onCreate and unregister in onDestroy.

The Observer is observing an object which do establish a tcp socket connection in a Thread and retry it onec it's disconnects (socket timeout).

I do also check with a broadcastreciever if the network connection changed and reconnect if needed.

What happen when the device go into standby? Do i really need an alarmmanager or timertask to recieve OR send the packet?

Does the Device drop the Connection onec it goes into standby?

Currently i tried sending from server to client with a 120 second delay and even when the devices display turned of its still possible to send the heartbeat.

But at least it looks like that the battery drain is not "acceptable".

So.. What is the best way to do that?

Thank you so far.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for doing this is using [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and a [Comet Server](https://github.com/cometd/cometd) or at least [NGinx](http://nginx.org/) with a [Push Stream Module](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module) and [Long Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_Polling). I've also created a service which return sticky and create a thread while starting. The thread connects. It still works even in standby and/or deep sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at socket.io there is an implementation for Android. I don't think that keeping the connection alive when the screen goes off is a good idea battery wise. I can't answer for all your questions, but I know that by default the Wi-Fi connection is killed when the device goes in standby on some devices (may also depend on user configured settings).

Comment: Thank you for that but it seems that its still connected since deacon does "almost" the same and it's working. 

https://github.com/davidrea/Deacon/blob/develop/src/org/deacon/MeteorPushReceiver.java

Well, i could not recognize any disconnects in Wifi with Standby but i guess this can happen after a while (likely if GC want it). But for this reason there is the service with return_sticky. Deacon does not have any battery issues (for example). Now, with a ping from server to client in a 2 second delay i couldnt recognize any battery drains. Well, the connection must be PERMANENTLY alive.

Comment: 2 seconds maybe a little bit fast. There is a system setting in the advanced wifi setting to prevent the device from disconnecting on standby.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Didnt know that. Well, on the galaxy s3 it was working successfully on wifi even with standby. GC destroyed the service but the thread was still running. When the thread is killed (but it takes not much memory so usually gc will not kill it) it will come back. The "2 Seconds" was just for batterie drain testing.  I guess 300 is a "good" interval. But this is still not the best solution. So, any improvements?

Answer (score 0):

For Java, there is a quite mature project implementing websocket and long-polling fallbacks: https://github.com/cometd/cometd. It also has quite lax license terms (BSD/Apache style).